# Webcam Color Changed To Grayscale

Tags: webcam, colors, camera

I was working with ROS and webcams were all of a sudden, the color output of the camera changed to grayscale. I tried on different computers but with no prevail. What should I do? I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using guvcview, you can run `guvcview -d /dev/video<id>` with your camera id(you can find that by running `ls /dev/video*`) and then it opens up with a GUI. Under the settings tab, you can restore to hardware defaults.